# upload csv/excel file to appengine (python) for processing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file, file-upload, csv

I need to be able to upload an excel or csv file to appengine so that the server can process the rows and create objects. Can anyone provide or point me to an example of how this is done? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Uploading to the [Blobstore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html) is probably what you are after. Then [reading](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass.html) the data and processing it with the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module.

You might want to look into sending your file to google docs in the case of excel (and other) formats then reading the rows back via the [Spreadsheets API](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a one-off (or a few) transfers, you're probably looking for the bulk upload system: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html

If you're talking about regular uploads during use, you'll need to handle them as post requests to the application.

Comment: What I would like to do is simply have a user go to a page where they upload a file from their computer. The server would then process it. I don't think bulkloader is what I want.

Comment: @Sam: No, if you're thinking of users uploading files, it's not what you want. You'll need to handle the post request from the upload, parse the data using the csv module (or xlrd for Excel), and put the data in the app store. Oh, and whatever you're doing has to be complete within the time limit for appengine requests, which I think is 30 seconds. I don't know of a neat example, though.

Comment: Doesn't have to be done in 30 seconds. That is what the task queue is for.

Comment: @Sam: I think you still have to be able to parse the file and queue the tasks within 30 seconds, though. It's probably not a problem unless you're using very big files.